# Ubuntu reset network configuration

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

When I boot up my ubuntu server, it cannot connect to my wireless network anymore. It says "waiting for network configuration" for 60 seconds, boots up, but no wireless.

I suspect it's because of the following reasons.

I used to connect to a wireless connection named 2WIRE555, password: 123abc
But then I upgraded my connection and my new wireless connection was named 2WIRE444, password:111111

Being lazy, I simply renamed 2WIRE555 to 2WIRE444 and changed the password accordingly.
I was hoping this would work but ever since then my network configurations is messed up.

So back to the issue, how do I reset my network configurations for my Ubuntu 11.10 server?

Answer (score 1):

The first example is for a WEP encrypted device.

```
wireless-essid 2WIRE555
```

The second is for a WPA encrypted device.

```
wpa-ssid 2WIRE444
```

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by editing two files:
/etc/resolv.conf and /etc/network/interfaces

i changed the nameserver of the old file `from 172.16.0.0 to 192.168.1.254`

i changed the /etc/network interfaces from

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wireless-mode managed
    wireless-essid 2WIRE555
    wireless-key1 123abc
```

to

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid 2WIRE444
    wpa-psk 111111
```

can anyone please explain to me the differences and why it worked?

Comment: In old settings you used WEP encryption and in new config you are using WPA encryption.